# Regex to match the number zero in the string

Tags: python-3.x, regex, regex-group

Can someone help me to get zeros in a separate group?

```
import re

text = 'fafsah000012fafaa'

zeroRegex = re.compile(r'^(\w*)((0)*\d*)(\w*)$')

matches = zeroRegex.search(text)

print(matches.groups())
```

Comment: Is there any part of the pattern that is obligatory? Or can the input be an empty string? Also, try `zeroRegex = re.compile(r'^([a-zA-Z]*)(0*)(\d*)([a-zA-Z]*)$')`

Comment: I just want to get a string without zeros if I would take a 0-s in separate group I would make a new string without that group and it would done

Comment: See https://ideone.com/gpJpBZ, does it work?

Comment: Thank you for this code but why \w does not works and [a-zA-Z] works?

Comment: `\w` also matches digits. If you used `\w` to match letters, or letters and `_`, you misused it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
zeroRegex = re.compile(r'^([a-zA-Z]*)(0*)(\d*)([a-zA-Z]*)$')
## Or, if you still need to match underscores and all Unicode letters and digits:
zeroRegex = re.compile(r'^([^\W\d]*)(0*)(\d*)([^\W\d]*)$')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VxGe28/1) and a [Python demo online](https://ideone.com/gpJpBZ).

Note that `\w*` matches any zero or more letters, digits or underscores in a greedy way. Making it non-greedy (like `\w*?`) would not help here because all the patterns are *optional* in this pattern, and if the first `\w*?` is skipped, the next `0*` and `\d*` would match at the very start of the string, and the last `\w*` or `\w*?` would grab the rest of the alphanumeric string.

Thus, the only way to get what you need and keep all subpatterns optional (so that even an empty string could be parsed with this regex), you need to "subtract" the digits from this pattern, and either use `[A-Za-z]*` to only match ASCII letters, or `[^\W\d]*`, to match any Unicode letters, underscores (and some other connector punctuation symbols, but that is usually not a problem).